# session is regenerated on each request, how to get the same session on each request

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cookies

When i have rewritten session as a class - session is regenerated on each request. ( Additionally, i added params to cookies, but now i disabled them).

I had a session, as an included file and I did not put any parameters to cookies. It was working.

I try this only on localhost.

My paths are not standard - i use kind of MVC and .htaccess file to convert url to Controller, Action and Parameters.

.htaccess
    Options -MultiViews
    Options -Indexes

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public/
IndexIgnore *  

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This means that from `www.domain/public/index.php/controllerName/actionName/parameters`
will be extracted `$_REQUEST['url'] = controllerName/actionName/parameters`

My Session Class:

```
<?php 

namespace nms;

use Bundle\SecureC\secureTr;  //generates random string

class SessionClass {

    use secureTr;

    private $action;   //current action
    private $path;     //current path 

    private $title;
    private $msgsessEnd;

    //part of OauthSession entity 
    private $sessName; //session name is the variable in the cookie
//The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. 
//Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() 
//or session_register() are called).

    private $timelimit;
    private $domain;
    private $securePath;
    private $ifhttps;
    private $ifhttponly; 
    private $sesdata;
    private $sesDataArr;
    private $sessCount;
    private $salt;
    private $sesskey;
    private $redirToken; 

    private $sessLooseIp;
    private $sessLooseAgent;
    private $sessProxyIp;
    private $sessStart;
    private $sessLastRestart;
    private $sessEnd;

    private $serverAddrArr;

    public function __construct($sessArr=[]) {

        $this->serverAddrArr = [];
        $this->serverAddrArr [] = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $this->serverName = [];
        $this->serverName[] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


        $status = session_status();
//PHP_SESSION_DISABLED - 0 if sessions are disabled. 
//PHP_SESSION_NONE - 1 if sessions are enabled, but none exists. 
//PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE -2 if sessions are enabled, and one exists.
        echo "<br><br> 96 Sessiong.php constructor status =". $status; 
        if( $status== 'PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE' ||  $status==2 ) {
            $this->sessId = session_id(); 
        } else {
            $this->sessId = false;
        }

        $this->timelimit = !empty($sessArr['timelimit']) ? $sessArr['timelimit'] : SESSION_TIMELIMIT;

        $this->domain = !empty($sessArr['domain']) ? $sessArr['domain'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //
        if(empty($domain)) { $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; }
        if(empty($domain)) { $domain = DOMAIN_wwwNAME; }


        $this->path = !empty($sessArr['curPath']) ? PREP.$sessArr['curPath'] : COOKIE_PATH;

        $this->ifhttps = (HTT == 'https://') ? true : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
        $this->ifhttps = isset($sessArr['ifhttps']) ? $sessArr['ifhttps'] : $this->ifhttps;

        $this->ifhttponly = isset($sessArr['ifhttponly']) ? $sessArr['ifhttponly'] : COOKIE_HTTPONLY;

        $this->sessLooseIp = long2ip(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long("255.255.0.0"));
        //check the beginning of string, because end may change, depending on device rotation on mobile and iPad 
        $this->sessLooseAgent = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,25); 

        //$redirToken = md5( uniqid(microtime(), true) ); 
        //$this->redirToken = 'rt_**_'. $redirToken .'_**_'. $this->genRandomStr(8); 

        $this->data = isset($sessArr['data']) ? $sessArr['data'] : []; //data here is vdArr; 

        //these are used for custom sessions, like payment session
        //tile - payment
        //msgsessEnd - Please start the payment from the beginning, because of long inactivity your data was lost.
        //you also can provide another timelimit
        $this->title = isset($sessArr['title']) ? $sessArr['title'] :""; //data here is vdArr; 
        $this->msgsessEnd = isset($sessArr['msgsessEnd']) ? $sessArr['msgsessEnd'] : 'After longer inactivity time you was log-out. Please login to continue'; //data here is vdArr;

        $this->ownDealSession(); //starts if needed
    }

    //not filly finished, because my application use javascript
    public function checkCookiesEnabled ($givArr) {
        setcookie("test_cookie", "test", time() + 3600, '/');
        $actionName = isset($givArr['actionName']) ? $givArr['actionName'] : 
        $this->htt->safeRedirct('security/checkcookie', true, true, [ 'cururl'=> $actionName ] ); 
    }


    public function ownSetCookieParams() {

        if( $this->ifhttponly) { 
            ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1); 
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            //echo "<br><br> 21 params after ini_set ="; print_r($params); 
        }
        //Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. 
        //The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. 
        //Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() 
        //for every request and before session_start() is called. 

        // Set the default secure value to whether the site is being accessed with SSL 
        session_set_cookie_params( $this->timelimit, $this->path, $this->domain, $this->ifhttps, $this->ifhttponly );
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        echo "<br><br> 21 Sessiong, cookie params after session_set_cookie_params ="; print_r($params); 
        // session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime 
        // [, string $path [, string $domain [,
        // bool $secure = false  - If TRUE cookie will only be sent over secure connections. 
        // [, bool $httponly = false - PHP will attempt to send the httponly flag when setting the session cookie. 

    } //function ownSetCookieParams($cooArr) {



    public function ownSetCookie() {
        //$cooArr= [ string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 
        //[, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, 
        //bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] ] 
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        echo "<br><br> 21 Sessiong, cookie params after session start ="; print_r($params); 
        $this->sessid = session_id();
        setcookie( $this->sessName, $this->sessid, $this->timelimit, $this->path,  $this->domain, $this->ifhttps ); 
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        echo "<br><br> 21 Sessiong, cookie params after setcookie ="; print_r($params); 
    }

    public function genRedirToken() {
        $this->redirToken = 'random string , most probably jwt token';
        $_SESSION['rt'] = $this->redirToken;
        return $this->redirToken; 
    }

    public function ownSetMainSessionParams($sesArr=[]) {

        $now = time(); // seconds
        $timelimit = !empty($sesArr['timelimit']) ? $sesArr['timelimit'] : $this->timelimit;

        $_SESSION['sessStart'] = $now;
        $_SESSION['sessEnd'] = $now + $timelimit;

        $_SESSION['userId'] = !empty($sesArr['userId']) ? $sesArr['userId'] : USER_ANONYMOUS_ID;
        $_SESSION['username'] = !empty($sesArr['username']) ? $sesArr['username'] : USER_ANONYMOUS_NAME;
        $_SESSION['roles'] = !empty($sesArr['roles']) ? $sesArr['roles'] : [ USER_ANONYMOUS_ROLES ];

        //$this->genRedirToken(); //$_SESSION['rt'] = $this->redirToken; $this->redirToken=generated str...

        $_SESSION['sessLooseIp'] = long2ip(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long("255.255.0.0"));
        $_SESSION['sessLooseAgent'] = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,25); 
    }




    // https://wblinks.com/notes/secure-session-management-tips/
    public function checkSession ($vdArr=[]) {

        $errSesArr = [];

        //- FINISH TO IMPLEMENT - check url parameters - must be part of custom request
        // but also applicable here  .... .

        //- FINISH TO IMPLEMENT
        //not always applicable, applicable only in case if not redirect
        //but i redirect only to login, logout, chars exercise, error, thus must be within these 
        //additionally during redirection there are only lang/redirToken paramemters, not more - double check parameters 
        //if ( isset($vdArr['path'] ) && ($_SESSION['prevPage'] != $vdArr['path'])  ){
        //    $errSesArr []  = "Path is different";  // means different browser
        //}

        //double check, because buffering may change path and PHP_SELF value !
        //$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php. 
        //The __FILE__ constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP
        if(!empty($vdArr['path'])) {
            if( 'public/index.php/'.$vdArr['path'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) {
                $errSesArr []  = "Path is different";  // means different browser
            }
        }

        if ($_SESSION['sessLooseIp'] != long2ip(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long("255.255.0.0")) ) {
            $errSesArr []  = "Loose Ip different";  // means different country
        }

        if ( $_SESSION['sessLooseAgent'] != substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,25) ){
            $errSesArr []  = "Useragent different";  // means different browser
        }

        if ( (!empty($vdArr['rt']) && !empty($_SESSION['rt']) && $_SESSION['rt'] != $vdArr['rt']) 
                || ( $_SESSION['sessCount'] == 0 && empty($vdArr['rt']) )// the first request, rt is not set. 
            ){
            $errSesArr []  = "Session token is different";  // means different browser
        }

        //server IP
        if( !in_array( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], $this->serverAddrArr ) ){
            $errSesArr[] = "Server address ".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']." is not amont safe listed. Contact the administrator";  // means different browse
        }

        //if( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != $this->serverName ) {
        if( !in_array( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $this->serverName  ) ){
            $errSesArr[] = "Server name ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']." is not the one considered to be safe.";
        }

        if ( $_SESSION['sessionId'] !== session_id()) {
            $errSesArr[] = "Session ID ". session_id() ." is invalud.";
        }

        //report error, 
        //record IP and other paramters commented-out below

        if( !empty($_SESSION['prevPath']) && ($_SESSION['prevPath']==$vdArr['path'] ) ) {
            //correct redirections are to ErrArr from any page, also 
            echo "<br><br> Sessiong, redirection. HERE must be redirection table check"; 
        } else {
            echo "<br><br> Sessiong, no redirection";
        } 
        // redirection - special function checking possible redirection from given MAP 
        //echo "<br><br>Sesssion.php 61 vdArr=<br>"; var_dump($vdArr);  
        //echo "<br><br>Sesssion.php 62 Session=<br>";var_dump($_SESSION); 
        if( !empty($vdArr['rt']) && ($vdArr['rt']===$_SESSION['rt']) ) {
            //proceed, everything is alright with redirection 
            echo "<br> 261 Session.php everyhting is alright with redirection"; 
        }
        //generate an error, record ip.
        else {
            //own_session_destory()
            echo '<br><br>  261 Session.php, you was redirected from wrong page'; 
        }


        if( !empty($errSesArr) ) { 
            //$this->own_logout($errSesArr); 
            echo "<br><br> FINISH implement, session.php 272 !empty(errSesArr)"; 
            print_r($errSesArr); 
            $errcode =  md5( uniqid(microtime(), true) ) . $this->genRandomStr(5) ;
            $msgErr = 'It was detected suspicious activities. Please re-login to continue or contact the administrator with err number :'.$errcode ;
            //delete session, create a new session 
            $this->ownSetMainSessionParams( [ 'msgErr'=>$msgErr ] ); 
            //redirect
        }
         // includes ownSessionDestroy(); , ownSessionStart(); userMsg, own_logout(), htt->login

    } //function checkSession () {



    public function ownSessionDestroy() {
        //https://wblinks.com/notes/secure-session-management-tips/
        setcookie( $this->sessName, $this->sessionId, 1); //The correct way to clear a cookie is to just pass in 1 as the expiry time. 
        session_unset();// Same as $_SESSION = array(); Destroy session on disk
        session_destroy();

    }



    public function ownDealExpiredSession() {
        $this->ownSessionDestroy();
        $this->ownSessionStart(); //generates a new redirToken 
        $msgErr = $this->msgsessEnd;
        //$this->ownSetMainSessionParams( [ 'msgErr'=>$msgErr ] );  
        echo "<br> 345 Session.php, session expired redirecting to login";
    } // public function ownDealExpiredSess() {

    public function ownSessionStart() {
        //ownCheckCookiesEnabled();
        $this->ownSetCookieParams();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sessCount'] = 0; 
        //$_SESSION['valid_id'] = session_id();
        $this->sessionId = session_id();
        $_SESSION['sessionId'] = $this->sessionId;
     //   $this->ownSetCookie();
        $this->ownSetMainSessionParams(); // does not generete redirToken
        echo "<br><br> 427 sessiong.php, After ownSessionStart _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION); 

    } //function ownSessionStart() {

    public function ownContinueSession() {
        //if( ( !empty($_SESSION['start'])) && ( $now <= ($_SESSION['start'] + $timelimit) ) ) {
        $now = time();
            $_SESSION['sessStart'] = $now; 
            $_SESSION['sessEnd'] = $now + $this->timelimit;
            $_SESSION['sessCount']++; //counts how many times session was activated
    }

    public function ownRegenerateSessionId() {
        $status = session_status();
        echo "<br><br> 448 Sessiong.php,  ownRegenerateSessionId  session_status=". $status;
        if( $status == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE || $status ==2 ) {
            $oldSession = $_SESSION;
            echo "session.php session is not expired, oldSession="; print_r($oldSession); 
            echo "session.php session is not expired, oldSessionId=".$this->sessionId;
            session_regenerate_id(true); //this destroys the old session, but others says it is wrong 
            $this->sessionId = session_id(); 
            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
            //$_SESSION['validId'] = $this->sessionId; 
            //regenerates redirToken
            echo "session.php session is not expired, newSession="; print_r($_SESSION);
            echo "session.php session is not expired, newSessionId=" .$this->sessionId;   
        }
    }

    public function ownDealSession() {

        // $_SESSION['rt'] = $token;   
        // Redir token 
        $now = time();
        //token to be retrieved from all redirections, to be compared if correct - part of this file 
         echo "<br><br> 462 ownDealSession, _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION);
         echo "<br>ownDealSession                now=" . $now;
        if(!isset($_SESSION) || empty($_SESSION) ) {
            echo "<br><br> 465 Sessiong.php  ownSessionStart";
            $this->ownSessionStart(); 
            echo "<br><br> case not set-empty, _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION); 

//if (!empty($_COOKIE[session_name()])) { setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-86400, 'https://www.typejoy.biz/'); }
        }

        // *** SESSION ALREADY EXISTS, but exceed the time limit
        else if ( !empty($_SESSION['sessStart']) && !empty($_SESSION['sessEnd']) && ( $now > intval($_SESSION['sessEnd'])) ) {
            echo "<br>ownDealSession  ase (!empty sessStart) and (now>sessEnd),now=" . $now;
            $this->ownDealExpiredSession(); 
            echo "<br><br> case (!empty sessStart) and (time>sessEnd),     _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION); 
        }    
        else if( !empty($_SESSION['sessStart']) && !empty($_SESSION['sessEnd']) && ( $now <= intval($_SESSION['sessEnd']) ) ) {
            echo "<br><br>474 Sessiong.php  (!empty sessStart) and (now<=sessEnd) ";
            echo "<br>ownDealSession           now=" . $now;
            $this->ownContinueSession(); 
            //$bsafe = $this->checkSession($vdArr); //redirect here 
           // $this->ownRegenerateSessionId(); 
            $this->genRedirToken(); 
            echo "<br><br> case (!empty sessStart) and (now<=sessEnd), _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION); 
        }// elseif( ( !empty($_SESSION['start'])) && ( $now <= ($_SESSION['start'] + $timelimit) ) ) {
        else {
            echo "<br><br>481, Sessiong not clear case";
            echo "<br>ownDealSession sessStart=" . $_SESSION['sessStart'];
            echo "<br>ownDealSession           now=" . $now;
            echo "<br>ownDealSession       sessEnd=" . $_SESSION['sessEnd'];
        }

        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        echo "<br><br> 508 Sessiong, cookie params in the end of ownDealSession ="; print_r($params);


        } //public function dealSession() {


    public function setIfEmpty($givArr){
        $retFull=[];
        foreach($givArr as $k=>$v) {
            if(empty($_SESSION[$k])) { $_SESSION[$k]=$v; }
            else { $retFull[] = $k; }
        } 
        return $retFull; //returns array with keys which have values in _SESSION
    }

    public function set($givArr) {
        foreach($givArr as $k=>$v) {
            $_SESSION[$k]=$v; 
        } 
    }

//if( isset($_SESSION['curPath']) ) { $_SESSION['prevPath'] = $_SESSION['curPath']; }
//if( isset($_SESSION['curAction']) ) { $_SESSION['prevAction'] = $_SESSION['curAction']; }
//$this->sess->setCond( [ 
//        [ 'vars'=> [ 'curPath'=>  $vdArr['path']  ], 'cond'=> isset($_SESSION['curPath']) ],  
//        [ 'vars'=> [ 'curAction'=>$vdArr['action']], 'cond'=> isset($_SESSION['curAction']) ],  
//    ] );   
    public function setCond($givArr) {
        foreach($givArr as $cond) {
            if($cond['cond']) { 
                foreach($cond['vars'] as $k=>$v) {
                    $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }}}}

} //
```

While debuging the session, i am getting the following:

1) in function ownDealSession, where i echo "462 ownDealSession, _SESSION="; print_r($_SESSION);

`Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in ...\Sessiong.php on line 477`

2) in function ownDealSession, after i create a new session

```
sessiong.php, After ownSessionStart _SESSION=Array ( [sessCount] => 0 [sessionId] => l89mnggsjmpgtp5n2dqsuo2rm6 [sessStart] => 1494406265 [sessEnd] => 1494409865 [userId] => 25 [username] => anon [roles] => Array ( [0] => IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ) [sessLooseIp] => 0.0.0.0 [sessLooseAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 1 [rt] => 'random string , most probably jwt token' [path] => democurpath [action] => democur30 ...
```

3) in function ownDealSession, after i create a new session

```
  508 Sessiong, cookie params in the end of ownDealSession =Array ( [lifetime] => 3600 [path] => /type705b/public/index.php/ [domain] => localhost [secure] => [httponly] => 1 )
```